# Formating time by minutes, by hours, by days etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

Friends, first of all I am new to javascript, and so please consider this question whether it comes under low priority too.

I need to show the created time of a post as 5 min ago, 1 hour ago, 1 day ago etc.. In hand the created time of the post is 2013-05-06T00:45:12.754Z . How can I convert the time as above.

Comment: Check out http://momentjs.com/ for date parsing.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall: Thanks for that. Had no idea it existed. Though typically i would do this on the serverside it might come in handy eventually.

Comment: I've found it extremely useful when working with jQuery UI Datepicker as well as when using front-end js frameworks. A .each function in the controller on a model works wonders when needing specific formatting.

Answer (score 2):

try using [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

> Timeago is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to support automatically updating 
>       fuzzy timestamps (e.g. "4 minutes ago" or "about 1 day ago").

examples:

> - You opened this page about a minute ago.
> - This page was last modified 27 days ago.
> - Ryan was born 34 years ago.